# Bug in seaborn's PairGrid function when passing an ordered string numeric variable?

Tags: python, seaborn

Here is a minimal example of `PairGrid` using `stripplot`  in `seaborn` from [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/pairgrid_dotplot.html):

```
# Load the dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes")

# Make the PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(crashes.sort_values("total", ascending=False),
                 x_vars=crashes.columns[:3], y_vars=["abbrev"],
                 height=7, aspect=.25)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h",
      palette="ch:s=1,r=-.1,h=1_r", linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

[image]

However, if my `y_vars` variables are numbers, even if they are strings, the sorting seems to follow the order of the string numbers:

```
crashes["new_col_1"] = crashes.index.map(str)
```

```
# Make the PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(crashes.sort_values("total", ascending=False),
                 x_vars=crashes.columns[:3], y_vars=["new_col_1"],
                 height=7, aspect=.25)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h",
      palette="ch:s=1,r=-.1,h=1_r", linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

[image]

If I add a letter to it, then it follows again the order given and desired:

```
crashes["new_col_2"] = "test_" + crashes.index.map(str)
```

```
# Make the PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(crashes.sort_values("total", ascending=False),
                 x_vars=crashes.columns[:3], y_vars=["new_col_2"],
                 height=7, aspect=.25)

# Draw a dot plot using the stripplot function
g.map(sns.stripplot, size=10, orient="h",
      palette="ch:s=1,r=-.1,h=1_r", linewidth=1, edgecolor="w")

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
```

[image]

Ideally, I would be able to provide string variables, even if they are numbers, and `PairGrid` would still follow the order I am giving to it.

Is this bug?

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2149#issuecomment-650128366

Below the answer from the [creator](https://github.com/mwaskom) of [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/):

> The behavior that you're seeing is half a bug and half an intentional but controversial API decision that has since been changed (obviating the bug).
>
> To be clear, the issue is in `stripplot` and has nothing to do with `PairGrid`.
>
> Up to `v0.10.1`, object-typed `Series` that could be coerced to a `float dtype` were considered "numeric" and treated as such. Categorical plots default to sorting the categorical variable if it's numeric. So sorting makes sense (in terms of what is intended to happen), but the bug in that example is that the string-encoded data is getting lexicographically sorted. The correct behavior would have been to sort the numeric representation.
>
> Either way, the API has changed in the development version, for `v0.11.0`. Now the type inference code introspects the types of the individual objects in an object-typed Series, so numbers encoded as strings are considered categorical, and `stripplot` uses the default ordering for categorical variables, which is the order they appear in the `Series`.
>
> In any case, you can always specify the order explicitly with the order parameter.